# What is the best practice to make an object in JS like this: T('isArray')([]) == T.run('isArray')([]) == T().run('isArray')?

Tags: javascript

What is the best practice to make an object in JavaScript like this, knowing `T` is the main object:

```
  T('isArray')([])
  T.run('isArray')([])
  T().run('isArray')([])

  T('isArray', [])
  T.run('isArray', [])
  T().run('isArray', [])
```

They all must use the same function.

Comment: I think an explanation what you need this for would be useful.

Comment: something similar to jquery/yui3

Comment: That explains exactly nothing. What are you trying to do, and why?

Comment: Ew. Please do it like : `T([]).isArray()` it's far nicer

Comment: It can't work becaus T itself will have some methods, and array is a function within the main package. There could be "array.isArray". The main problem appears when I have the "isArray" method on T.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the main object can be called it must be a function. The function should decide what to return based on the arguments:

```
var T = (function() {

    var functions = { // define functions that can be run like isArray
        isArray: function(a) {
            return Array.isArray(a);
        },

        log: function(a, b) {
            console.log(a + b);
        }
    };

    var noop = function() {}; // function doing nothing (no operation)

    var T = function(f) {
        if(arguments.length >= 2) { // function + args provided
            return (functions[f] || noop) // call it
                    .apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments, 1));
        } else if(arguments.length === 1) { // only function provided
            return function() { // return function that can be called with args
                return (functions[f] || noop)
                        .apply(this, arguments);
            }
        } else { // nothing provided, return T itself (so that e.g. T.run === T().run)
            return T;
        }
    }

    T.run = function() { // run function
        return T.apply(this, arguments);
    };

    T.getState = function() { // another function
        console.log("Not implemented");
    };

    return T; // actually return T so that it gets stored in 'var T'
})();


// tests

console.log(
    T('isArray')([]),
    T.run('isArray')([]),
    T().run('isArray')([]),

    T('isArray', []),
    T.run('isArray', []),
    T().run('isArray', [])
);

T('log')(1, 2);
T.getState();
```

Comment: I didn't specify, but the T object might have other methods as: load, instance, getState. But the main should always be the "run" method

Comment: and "a" will be used as arguments as there will not only be the "isArray" method and have diferent argument number

Comment: @Totty: I'm not sure, but even complex libraries like jQuery don't have that bad of an performance so I wouldn't worry about that.

Comment: one more question: I would need it to multiple instances, but how do I use the same "prototype"?

Comment: @Totty: I'm not entirely sure what you mean. Could you provide a code example that you want to use?

Comment: Imagine I would want multiple instances (for other purposes in this case) how do I do? (with a look at performance too)